# Подчеркивание текста css

Tags: css

Подскажите как сделать такое подчеркивание текста (текст заголовка для примера он может быть любой длины)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При использовании before он подчеркивает последнюю строку, а если делать через border-bottom то по дизайну он должен быть выше

[codepen](https://codepen.io/1katerina9/pen/eYvZGpj)

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
} 
h2 { 
     font-size: 50px; 
     position: relative; 
     display: inline;
}
.style1::before {
    content: ''; 
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #f84343;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
} 
.style2{
  border-bottom: 15px solid red;
}
```

```html
 
   <h2 class="style1">Культурный речевой акт в XXI веке</h2>
<p>Действительно, мифопорождающее текстовое устройство 
    иллюстрирует дискурс, и это придает ему свое звучание, 
    свой характер.</p>    
<h2 class="style2">Культурный речевой акт в XXI веке</h2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать тень. Ниже два варианта (цвет сделал полупрозрачным для наглядности):

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.style1 {
  box-shadow: 0 -30px 0 -15px RGBA(255, 0, 0, 0.75) inset;
}

.style2 {
  z-index: -1;
}

.overlay2 {
  box-shadow: 0 -30px 0 -15px RGBA(255, 0, 0, 0.75) inset;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
Подчеркивание ПОД текстом: <br/>
<h2 class="style1">Культурный речевой акт в XXI веке</h2>
<br><br><br><br>Подчеркивание НАД текстом: <br/>
<span class="overlay2"><h2 class="style2">Культурный речевой акт в XXI веке</h2></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

На счет кросс-браузерной совместимости есть сомнения, но на хроме работает.
Трудность возникает из-за перекрытия текста подчеркиванием - прибегнул к трюку с прозрачным текстом и обрезкой фона по контуру.

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.style1 {
  background: currentColor;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  text-underline-offset: -0.4em;
  text-decoration-thickness: 0.5em;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.style2 {
  border-bottom: 15px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="style1">Культурный речевой акт в XXI веке</h2>
<p>Действительно, мифопорождающее текстовое устройство иллюстрирует дискурс, и это придает ему свое звучание, свой характер.</p>
```